# How to suppress Microsoft.Maintainability issue CA1505 for a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, fxcop

My class 'Common' has CA1505 violation.

CA1505 : Microsoft.Maintainability : 'Common' has a maintainability index of 16. Rewrite or refactor the type's methods to increase its maintainability index (MI). An MI below 10 indicates poor maintainability, an MI between 10 and 20 indicates moderate maintainability, and an MI above 20 indicates

How to suppress this violation since it's very difficult to split.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the latest toolset, you right-click on the warning and select "suppress in source" from the context menu.

However, you should really improve the class. It might be difficult to split *now*, but just imagine how difficult it will be in the future.